# How to compare two JavaPairRDD by key and compare value?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I'd like to use Java Spark to compare two JavaPairRDD based on their keys, compare their values to see if the same key has exactly the same values.

Right now, I'm only checking the count() of intersection and union, but this is not enough, like below:

```
        JavaPairRDD<String, String> intersectionJavaPairRDD = hBaseJavaPairRDD.intersection(hiveJavaPairRDD);
        JavaPairRDD<String, String> unionJavaPairRDD = hBaseJavaPairRDD.union(hiveJavaPairRDD).distinct();

        if (intersectionJavaPairRDD.count() != unionJavaPairRDD.count()
            || hiveJavaPairRDD.count() != hBaseJavaPairRDD.count()) {
            System.err.println(
                "ERROR: SxS validation failed...");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
```

How can I compare each value when they have the same key?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use combineByKey / AggregateByKey to compare values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm coming from scala but I do believe that with a little syntax changes it will work also for java.

My idea is to join the Two `RDD`s and then compare the two columns of values.

```
val isEquals = hBaseJavaPairRDD
              .join(hiveJavaPairRDD)
              .map {
                case (id, (v1, v2)) => v1 == v2
              }
              .reduce(_ && _)
```

The idea behind this solution is the following :

1. For each **Key** we put the the values of the first and the second `RDD`s in the same row. This is performed with the `join` operation.
2. Map the results (**joined `RDD`**) so that for each row we put `true` if the two values are equals `false` otherwise
3. Then applying a `reduce` function on this **mapped `RDD`** with the **AND** as a binary operation between elements.

Applying the `reduce` function returns `true` if all the elements in the **joined `RDD`** are `true` i.e. **all the values are equals**, `false` otherwise.

Sorry for answering in scala, hope it helps